# typesafe config cannot parse url with variable

Tags: sbt, sbt-native-packager, typesafe-stack, typesafe-config

I need to connect to a PostgreSQL server based on ENV variables. The ENV vars are set by Docker. I'm using sbt-native-packager to create a docker container of my akka/play project.

So i tried to add the variables to my conf:

```
db{
  default {
    host=${POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR}
    driver=org.postgresql.Driver
    url=jdbc:postgresql://${host}:5432/mail_archive
    user=username
    password=password
  }
}
```

unfortunately the config file cannot be parsed anymore:

> 45: Expecting close brace } or a comma, got ':' (if you intended ':'
>   to be part of the value for 'url', try enclosing the value in double
>   quotes, or you may be able to rename the file .properties rather than
>   .conf)

(where 45 is the url= line)

When using " around the url string, the ${host} variable is not being replaced anymore and the play application will throw a HostNotFoundException.

Does anybody have a suggestion how to include the ENV variable in the JDBC url used within the typesafe config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
url="jdbc:postgresql://"${host}":5432/mail_archive"
```

Comment: What if my config want to provide host and port together? such as `url="jdbc:postgresql://"${host_port}"/mail_archive"`. It will complain about the same thing again. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66561026/typesafe-config-override-with-colon-including-variable, thank you!