# Typesafe config override with colon-including variable

Tags: maven, typesafe-config

I am using Typesafe Config to manage my Flink SQL command. For example,

```
source = """
CREATE TABLE kafka_source (
    `body` ROW<`log` ROW<`uid` BIGINT, serverts BIGINT, `contentstr` STRING>>
) WITH (
    'connector' = 'kafka',
    'topic' = 'data-report-stat-old-logtype7',
    'properties.bootstrap.servers' = '10.111.135.233:9092',
    'properties.group.id' = 'flink-test2',
    'json.fail-on-missing-field' = 'false',
    'format' = 'json'
)
"""
```

My `properties.bootstrap.servers` is maven-profile specific, therefore I want to configure it in Maven pom.xml

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>testing</id>
        <properties>
            <kafka.source.servers>10.111.135.233:9092</kafka.source.servers>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

And I would like to reference and use the property in Typesafe config,

```
source = """
CREATE TABLE kafka_source (
    `body` ROW<`log` ROW<`uid` BIGINT, serverts BIGINT, `contentstr` STRING>>
) WITH (
    'connector' = 'kafka',
    'topic' = 'data-report-stat-old-logtype7',
    'properties.bootstrap.servers' = '"""${kafka.source.servers}"""',
    'properties.group.id' = 'flink-test2',
    'json.fail-on-missing-field' = 'false',
    'format' = 'json'
)
"""
```

However, if I run `mvn clean package -Ptesting`, the config is built into

```
source = """
CREATE TABLE kafka_source (
    `body` ROW<`log` ROW<`uid` BIGINT, serverts BIGINT, `contentstr` STRING>>
) WITH (
    'connector' = 'kafka',
    'topic' = 'data-report-stat-old-logtype7',
    'properties.bootstrap.servers' = '"""10.111.135.233:9092"""',
    'properties.group.id' = 'flink-test2',
    'json.fail-on-missing-field' = 'false',
    'format' = 'json'
)
"""
```

and it throws exceptions when loading the config, because `10.111.135.233:9092` contains a `:`:

```
Expecting close brace } or a comma, got ':' (if you intended ':' to be part of a key or string value, try enclosing the key or value in double quotes
```

What is the right way to solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is an issue from typesafe config. To solve the problem, use `application.properties` file instead of `application.conf`.

```
last-n-clicks.generation-ingestion.source=\
CREATE TABLE kafka_source ( \
`body` ROW<`log` ROW<`uid` BIGINT, serverts BIGINT, `contentstr` STRING>> \
) WITH ( \
'connector' = 'kafka', \
'topic' = 'data-report-stat-old-logtype7', \
'properties.bootstrap.servers' = '${kafka.source.servers}', \
'properties.group.id' = 'flink-test2', \
'json.fail-on-missing-field' = 'false', \
'format' = 'json' \
)
```